# Why does for loop not iterate with (i in 1:1523)?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have run into errors with my for loop. The code is as follows:

```
#finding IDs with >5% replicate variance
#initialize vectors
LS1repvariance = NULL 
anomalylist = NULL

#open for loop iterating from 1 to end of dataset
for (i in 1:1523){ 
  #call replicates, which start off as characters
  charrep1 = widesubdat[i,2] 
  charrep2 = widesubdat[i,11]

  #convert to numeric 
  rep1 = as.numeric(charrep1) 
  rep2 = as.numeric(charrep2) 

  #calculation
  repvariance = (rep1-rep2)/((rep1+rep2)/2)*100 

  #if loop for anomalous replicates
  if (abs(repvariance)>=5) 
    anomalylist[i]=widesubdat[i,0] 
  }
```

The error I get says

> Error in if (abs(repvariance) >= 5) anomalylist[i] = widesubdat[i, 0]
>   :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I think the error is in the iteration because it defines i as 336L, and it does not call charrep correctly, but I have no idea why. I've done for loops in python but never in R, but all of the for loop help pages seem to have the same structure. All of the lines that I can run outside of the for loop test out okay.

I've read that if statements also require curly brackets, but IDLE said unexpected "{" when I used them.

Comment: `widesubdat[i,0]` is not correct. R starts indexing at 1, not at 0.

Comment: That wouldn't produce an error though.  You probably have an NA value in `repvariance` causing that error. `if(NA) 1 else 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also drop the loop

```
pick <- abs(200*(widesubdat[,2]-widesubdat[,11])/(widesubdat[,2]+widesubdat[,11]))>=5
anomalylist <- widesubdat[,1]  # Note the comment above with index 0
anomalylist[!pick] <- NA
```